How to fix "does not contain : exactly once" Yasnippet warning?
I have the following yasnippet warning message for each major mode and .yas-parents directory:
yatemplate: ~/snippets/org-mode does not contain : exactly once
yatemplate: ~/snippets/lua-mode does not contain : exactly once

What's causing it and how to fix it?

It looks like it wants the filenames found in yatemplate-dir to contain exactly one : and it's not seeing that.
I don't use this, so I can't tell you any more.  (I just grepped the code for the error message.)
(defun yatemplate-sorted-files-in-dir ()
  "Return a sorted list of files in the template directory."
  (sort (file-expand-wildcards (concat (file-name-as-directory yatemplate-dir) "*")) 'string<))

(defun yatemplate-regex-from-filename (FILENAME)
  "Split the regular expression from FILENAME and return it."
  (let ((split-name (split-string FILENAME yatemplate-separator)))
    (if (eq (length split-name) 2)
        ;; Add the dollar sign for end-of-string automatically since the last
        ;; characters of the filename are most likely a file extension.
        (concat (nth 1 split-name) "$")
      (progn
        (unless (string-match yatemplate-ignored-files-regexp FILENAME)
          (message "yatemplate: %s does not contain %s exactly once"
                   FILENAME yatemplate-separator))
        nil))))

;;;###autoload
(defun yatemplate-fill-alist ()
  "Fill `auto-insert-alist'."
  (yatemplate-remove-old-yatemplates-from-alist)
  (dolist (filename (reverse (yatemplate-sorted-files-in-dir)) nil)
    (let ((file-regex (yatemplate-regex-from-filename filename)))
      (if file-regex
          (push `(,file-regex . [,filename yatemplate-expand-yas-buffer])
                auto-insert-alist)))))

Where yatemplate-separator defaults to :.

tree ~/dotfiles/snippets | grep ':' returns nothing, no filenames with : sign, that's why I got confused. I'll post an update if I find a solution to this later
